# Four standard deviation rules in relation to normality testing

Tags: standard-deviation, normality-assumption, continuous-data, nonparametric

Within our department we were given a set of guidelines for how we might decide whether to proceed with parametric or non-parametric testing (for continuous data). These were drawn up in consultation with a statistician so I am reasonably confident that they are good points. One rule given was that if the data set violated normality and homogeneity of variance based on the results of the Shapiro-Wilk and Levene's tests that we could still run parametric tests if the standard deviations of all the groups was within 4 times the lowest standard deviation - so if the lowest SD was 4 then if the rest of the SDs did not exceed 16 then we could proceed with parametric tests. I thought maybe it was something to do with the idea that most of the data in a hypothetical normal distribution is contained within 3 SDs but I don't really know.

I am not a fan of prescriptive lists, especially when there is no explanation so if anyone could shed light on this I would appreciate it.